# Performing indexOf on object passed via child in Parent's Proxy Array return -1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

We have some Lightning component which was built when API version was around 39, and we are slowly migrating to V40.

There are lots of places where we send child's object to parent component and extensively do `indexOf` on the parent's array attribute.

In V39, `indexOf` works properly but in V40 it always returns **-1**.

Here's a sample:

**Child.cmp:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="messageToParent" type="c:MsgToParent" />
    <div>
        <a onclick="{!c.sendToParent}">{!v.record.label}</a>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**ChildController.js**

```
({
    sendToParent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = component.getEvent("messageToParent");
        evt.setParams({
            "record" : component.get("v.record")
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

**TestAppController.cmp:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler name="messageToParent" event="c:MsgToParent"  action="{!c.checkIndexOf}" />

    <aura:attribute name="records" type="List" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
        <c:child record="{!record}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

**TestAppController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function( cmp, evt, h ) {
       var records = [
           {
               'label' : '1'
           },
           {
               'label' : '2'
           },
           {
               'label' : '3'
           }
       ];
        cmp.set("v.records", records);
    },
    checkIndexOf : function( cmp, evt, h ) {
        var records = cmp.get("v.records");
        console.log(records.indexOf(evt.getParam("record")))
    },
})
```

As a workaround, I pass the value of the `indexVar` of the `aura:iteration` to the child component and pass it along with the data in the event when sent to the parent.

Not sure what the Proxy stuff messing things up.

It's a pain for us to test everything and do the necessary changes every time when something new stuff comes in LC.

Comment: The above usecase is assuming that when the child passes the record back to the parent as a event param, it is passing a reference to the original record. But that is not what happens underneath. When LockerService is enforced, the event params are sanitized(to filter items not owned by the handler) and that is where the proxy comes in. To do this we deep clone the original object and pass a copy. Hence, the equality check on the objects fails. This expressions "records[0].label === evt.getParam("record").label" returns true. I will file a bug for us to see if we can support this.

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa Thank you for replying. If possible, can you please update the thread if there's an update on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@praveen, this is an issue with the current version of LockerService. It happens in several situations, and we are working hard to fix it. In my mind, the system should be self-evident and the developer should not have to work around its limitations, unless for security reasons.

The issue you are facing is with identity discontinuity: `Array.indexOf()` performs a reference identity check on the object (aka a `===`) and due to the mechanics of LockerService, that fails.

Now, if I understand your design, you are creating a UI based on a list of records. Those records have several properties such as a label. The parent generates the UI, a list of children, and acts as an event aggregator for the events fired from the children.

The way to get around the problem is to use primitives to find who fired the event. To simplify, consider this:

```
{} === {} // false
1 === 1 // true
"abc" === "abc" // true
```

Here is what I suggest:

A. For each record item, assign an `id`. You can use a property on the helper that keeps the current id:

```
({
    lastId: 0,
    getNextId: function() {
        return this.lastId++;
    }
})
```

Helpers are singletons, and `lastId` will be unique for your whole app.

B. As you loop through your records, you can assign the `id` to your record, or better, keep a map of `id:record` which would keep your record immutable.

C. Add an `id` property to you child component, and your click handler becomes:

```
sendToParent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = component.getEvent("messageToParent");
    evt.setParams({
        "id" : component.get("v.id")
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

D. Your parent then can find the proper record:

```
checkIndexOf : function( cmp, evt, h ) {
    var id = evt.getParam("id");
    var records = cmp.get("v.records");
    var result = records.find(function(item) { return item.id === id });
    console.log(result);
},
```

Using `Array.find()` will be more efficient than firing an event with an object.

There are many other ways to solve that problem, and I hope that this has given you a few ideas.

Comment: Regarding the -1, I suspected it was due to equality which is happening behind the scene in locker service, thanks for confirming it and thanks for the workaround too.